# JavaScript Get values from array but ignore duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains different clothes and the type of the cloth. For example, I may have a specific shirt that belongs to the shirts category. What I want to do is get all the types from an array and ignore any duplicate entries. So if I have 3 shirts and 2 trousers, I will only get 1 shirt and 1 trouser.

```
array = [
    {
        name: "test 1",
        type: "shirt"
    },
  {
        name: "test 2",
        type: "shirt"
    },
  {
        name: "test 3",
        type: "trousers"
    },
  {
        name: "test 4",
        type: "trousers"
    }
];

var categories = {};
for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(categories.indexOf(array[i].type) > -1) {
    console.log('Duplicate type');
  }
  else {
    console.log('New type');
    categories.push(array[i].type);
  }
}
```

But I end up getting TypeError: categories.indexOf is not a function.

Comment: Agreed with @A.Rossi, you need to apply if condition in your `array`

Comment: categories is defined as an object (not ordered) so there is no indexOf.

Comment: @ibab Don't listen to them. Read the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an array for categories, not an object.

```
var categories = [];
```

```js
array = [
    {
        name: "test 1",
        type: "shirt"
    },
  {
        name: "test 2",
        type: "shirt"
    },
  {
        name: "test 3",
        type: "trousers"
    },
  {
        name: "test 4",
        type: "trousers"
    }
];

var categories = [];
for(var i = 0, len = array.length; i < len; i++) {
    if(categories.indexOf(array[i].type) > -1) {
    console.log('Duplicate type');
  }
  else {
    console.log('New type');
    categories.push(array[i].type);
  }
}
console.log(categories);
```

Comment: its from the op. i have no laptop.

Answer (score 4):

Pretty short solution using ES6 `Set` object:

> The **Set** object lets you store unique values of any type, whether
>   primitive values or object references.

```
var categories = new Set();
array.forEach((o) => categories.add(o.type));
categories = [...categories];  // Set to Array transformation

console.log(categories);  // ["shirt", "trousers"]
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you define `categories` as object literal (`{}`), rather than an array (`[]`):

```
// --------------vv
var categories = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you are trying to invoke `.push` method on an object but the method is available only on Array. You need to make categories an array in order to push to it.

As an alternative, you can use pure function without any mutations using `Array.prototype.reduce()` to reduce the array of duplicate objects to unique ones:

```js
var array = [
    {
        name: "test 1",
        type: "shirt"
    },
  {
        name: "test 2",
        type: "shirt"
    },
  {
        name: "test 3",
        type: "trousers"
    },
  {
        name: "test 4",
        type: "trousers"
    }
];


function unique(input) {
  return input.reduce(function (acc, current) {
    if (acc.indexOf(current.type) > -1) {
      return acc 
    } else {
      return acc.concat([current.type]);
    }
  }, [])
  
}

var categories = unique(array);
console.log(categories);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the result of every row then I think first implementation could be the answer but if you want just the `categories` then using map make it simple.

```js
array = [
 { name: "test 1", type: "shirt" }, 
 { name: "test 2", type: "shirt" }, 
 { name: "test 3", type: "trousers" }, 
 { name: "test 4", type: "trousers" }
];

// --------------------------------------
var categories = [];
array.forEach(v => {
 if (this[v.type])
  return console.log('Duplicate type');
 console.log('New type');
 this[v.type] = true;
 categories.push(v.type);
}, {});

console.log(categories);
// --------------------------------------
var map = new Map;
array.forEach(v => map.set(v.type, v.type));
categories = [...map.keys()];

console.log(categories);
```